# К общей сумме товара в корзине прибавить значение

Tags: php, cms, modx, revo

Подскажите как при формировании общей суммы в корзине товара прибавить значение тв поля этого товара 
 файл `mscarthandler.class.php`

```
public function status($data = array())
    {
        $status = array(
            'total_count' => 0,
            'total_cost' => 0,
            'total_weight' => 0,
        );
        foreach ($this->cart as $item) {
            if (empty($item['ctx']) || $item['ctx'] == $this->ctx) {
                $status['total_count'] += $item['count'];
                $status['total_cost'] += ($item['price'] * $item['count']) + значение тв поля p1;
                $status['total_weight'] += $item['weight'] * $item['count'];
            }
        }

        return array_merge($data, $status);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно каждый раз добавлять TV параметр к стоимости каждого товара? Передавайте доп параметр в функцию в том месте, где вызываете ее (поставил значение по умолчанию, вдруг не всегда нужно добавлять)

```
public function status($data = array(), $add = 0)
{
    $status = array(
        'total_count' => 0,
        'total_cost' => 0,
        'total_weight' => 0,
    );
    foreach ($this->cart as $item) {
        if (empty($item['ctx']) || $item['ctx'] == $this->ctx) {
            $status['total_count'] += $item['count'];
            $status['total_cost'] += ($item['price'] * $item['count']) + $add;
            $status['total_weight'] += $item['weight'] * $item['count'];
        }
    }

    return array_merge($data, $status);
}
```

Comment: в этой функции $item- выводит данные текущего товара, я могу узнать его id $item['id'] b и по этому id мне нужно вытащить значение тв p1

Comment: А Вы можете сразу передавать `$item` вместе со значением TV? Потому что писать запросы в БД в данной функции не очень хорошая идея.